# Mangento Unable to create directory while uploading product image

Tags: admin, product, magento-1.8, image-upload

Am very new to magento, created one site using magento. All the functionality are working fine in localhost. When am upload that code into online(server), i got one issue. except that all functionality are working fine.

```
While am uploading an image i got the issue "Unable to create directory".
Images are uploading to tmp path but not moving to target path. Because when am press the button 'upload files', I can able to see the upload percentages. That is why am thing the files are not moving due to dynamic directory creation fails.

I have tried lot but i can't able to make it as work.

I had tried the following solution,
  1. Changed the media file permission to 777.
  2. Created one tmp directory under /var/ directory and assigned manually in as tmp directory by change the line 91 of lib/Zend/Cache/Backend/File.php ('cache_dir' => null to 'cache_dir' => 'var/tmp').
  3. Changed the php.ini file under the magento root directory.
     Newly added lines are,
         magic_quotes_gpc = off
         short_open_tag = on
         extension=pdo.so
         extension=pdo_mysql.so
  4. Checked whether GD library installed or not. It was installed.
  5. Changed scope attribute in Magento admin panel -> Catalog -> Attributes -> Manage attributes. After this you should find image, small_image & thumbnail attributes. Then am changed all these attributes scope to Global.
```

Many thanks in advance. Please share your thoughts. Feel free to post your comment also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I got solution at 22-Aug-2014.

Problem is PHP version issue, megento need php 5.2.13 but my server contains php 5.2.12

After updated php version, image upload working fine.